# Composition of HTML view of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, phtml, html

How a HTML view of **Magento 2** composed ? I know this is a broad question.

Actually I am trying to remove Header and Footer from Print out of Sales Order. I can see a HTML view of **Magento 2** when I am browsing this URL `https://chaldal.com/sales/order/print/order_id/13/`.I need to remove some portion of this HTML view. In this regard I turned on `Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront`. I found that there is no main .phtml file which has to contain all the **.phtml** file.So that I can remove some of the .phtml files and keep some of them to have my desired **HTML** view.

I have to remove these .phtml files `/home/theuaeex/public_html/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml`

`/home/theuaeex/public_html/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magiccart_Magicproduct/templates/productcustom.phtml` and `/home/theuaeex/public_html/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml`.

I tried through **`.xml`** files to remove those inclusion but failed.

Here is my `print.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-print"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
        <move element="logo" destination="main.content" before="-" />
        <move element="copyright" destination="main.content" after="-" />
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sales.order.print.js" template="Magento_Theme::html/print.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy layout from

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/print.xml
```

to

```
/home/theuaeex/public_html/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magento_Theme/layout/print.xml
```

and use the layout handle

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="print" />
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Or you can remove the header footer

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks @Qaisar Satti for your reply. I tried your solution but it is not working. Thanks

Comment: @abuabu share your update layout code so i can look at that

Comment: I updated my question with my `print.xml` file code which is copied to `/home/theuaeex/public_html/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magento_Theme/layout`. Thanks

Comment: @abuabu just copy `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print.xml` to `/home/theuaeex/public_html/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magneto_Sales/layout/sales_order_print.xml'` then check the output

Comment: should I copy two files ? Thanks

Comment: @abuabu if layout file is not their then copy maybe it is causing the problem? else i checked this code with custom theme it is working

Comment: Thanks @Qaisar Satti for your reply. I made a folder there and copied two files. But the result is as like before. no change.  Do you have any clue ? What should I do ? Thanks

Comment: @abuabu no other clue .

Comment: thanks for reply. I installed default `Luma` theme with some sample products and found that this theme is not printing `header` and `footer`. But my theme is printing `header` and `footer`. Why this is happening ?  Thanks

Comment: can you say which XML file is responsible for this ?

Comment: this example is responsible for removing header and footer `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/print.xml`